# PDFTron - restoring state

Tags: java, android, pdftron, pdfnet

It seems that Bug in PDFTrone - after adding text annotation for highlighted text - position, zoom and scale reset.
It not critical for device with screen/resolution but it looks not good for devices with small screen.
Because document zoom after this will be set to 0.05 or similar small value.

So may question - how to detect that text note was added and handle this situation? I'm sure that it's possible because when pdf is rotated, previous normal zoom will be restored.

PS I decompiled library and know line where is an error but my question is still actual:
file PDFViewCtrl

```
  protected void onLayout(boolean var1, int var2, int var3, int var4, int     var5) {
    int var6 = var4 - var2;
    int var7 = var5 - var3;
    if(this.R != var6 || this.S != var7 || this.b == null || this.p || this.ay) {
        boolean var8 = this.R != var6 || this.S != var7;
        this.S = var7;
        this.R = var6;
        if(this.b != null && this.R > 0 && this.S > 0) {
            this.cancelRendering();
            this.ay = false;
            OnSize(this.bq, this.R, this.S, this.R, false);
            if(this.p) {
                this.p = false;
                var8 = true;
                this.setPagePresentationMode(this.ba);
                this.setPageViewMode(this.aZ);
                this.scrollTo(0, 0);
                this.aC = this.getZoom();
                this.aO = this.getCurrentPage();
                this.aN = this.aO;
                if(this.aX != null) {
                    this.aX.onSetDoc();
                }
            }

            if(var8) {
                this.h.b();
            }

            this.b();
            this.scrollTo(this.k(), this.l());
        } else if(this.b == null) {
            this.T = 0;
            this.U = 0;
        }

        if(var1 && this.b != null && this.aB == 2) {
            boolean var16 = !this.isFinishedRendering();
            double var10 = this.getZoom();
            this.cancelRendering();
            this.aC = this.e();
            double var12 = this.az * this.aC;
            double var14 = this.aA * this.aC;
            if(var10 < var12) {
                this.setZoom(var12);
            }

            if(var10 > var14) {
            // error here - will be set extremely small zoom
                this.setZoom(var14);
            }

            if(var16) {
                this.requestRendering();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe @Ryan  from PDFTron can help?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in our unmodified SDK sample, or does this only occur in your project?